# Нестандартный заголовок окна

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Доброго времени суток!

Все наверняка знают, что такое QIP. У них при запуске программы выскакивает форма авторизации. Вопрос в том - как они зделали такое оформление? Возможно ли средствами C# такое натворить? Для тех, кто не обращал внимания, кидаю скриншот.

[image: снимок QIP]

Поделитесь ссылками, у кого есть, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Для того, чтобы создать сие чудо, используется DWM API.

Вот пара ссылок:

1. Статья на MSDN: **Создание специальных эффектов с помощью диспетчера окон рабочего стола / Aero Glass: Create Special Effects With The Desktop Window Manager** *(К cожалению оригинальная прямая ссылка больше недоступна, но можно [скачать журнал](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineApril2007en-us.chm) с этой статьей или посмотреть страницу в [архиве](http://web.archive.org/web/20140320173627/http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc163435.aspx))*
2. Немного информации на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/personal/59899/)

Comment: Спасибо! невероятно классная статья. плюсую!)

Answer (score -2):

Вообще-то это всё графика - заранее сделанные картинки и прочее, даже при попытке подключения бежит типа своего рода progressbar - так вот это всего лишь bmp, которые меняют друг друга благодаря таймерам. Программа сделана на delphi? И если (я не работал с С#) является ООЯП, то можно сделать подобное и на этом языке.