# Замена стандартного окна

Tags: windows, visual-basic

Скажите, а можно заменить стандартное окно Windows в Visual Basic 2010 на какое-то другое. Спасибо.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Вполне можно, особенно если действовать через DWM API: [нестандартный заголовок окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18609/#18613).

Comment: Ен-то как я не понял

Answer (score 0):

В параметрах формы есть выбор стиля формы, например с различным набором кнопок (закрыть, свернуть, развернуть), а также различного поведения (например когда окно без кнопок, без шапки и по верх всех остальных). Можно с этим параметром поиграться. А вообще на что необычное хотите заменить? Окна они везде стандартные. Знаю что на Assemblere можно углы скруглять и в таком плане с окнами играться.

Answer (score 0):

Времена висты то давно прошли =) Если есть возможность сделать [WPF](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) приложение, то там можно любые окна, любые стили делать. Если стандартный **WinForm**, то тогда все-равно без картинок никуда.