# Собственный интерфейс

Tags: интерфейс, visual-studio

Хочу созрать приложение в среде Visual Studio с собственным интерфейсом, то есть без окон, аза основу взять свое собственое изображение. Где можно найти информацию о создании подобных приложений или какие библиотеки надо юзать для этого?

Comment: Вы бы указали, что будете использовать: какой язык, технологию. А то вопрос получается абстрактный.

Comment: @Shad: и операционную систему, в принципе, а то вдруг под VS кросс-компилятор есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам поможет данная тема, закрыта она была уже давно, но в избранных у меня все еще сохранилась

[Нестандартный заголовок окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18609/c-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Answer (score 1):

Гуглить по запросу "create custom window frame"

[Irregular-Shaped Windows Form  Transparency](http://www.vcskicks.com/custom_shape_form_transperancy.php).